# Using rmagick to colorize an image like in photoshop

Tags: image, colors, imagemagick, rmagick, colorize

So I have this base image:

[image]

And in photoshop I do a basic layer color overlay, with the rgb colors:

r: 244, g: 93, b: 0

This gives me the amazingly vibrant:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is colorize the same image in rmagick, so if I do the following colorize:

```
  img = Magick::Image.read('brush.png').first
  img = img.colorize(100, 100, 100, Magick::Pixel.new(244, 93, 0, 1))
  img.format = 'png'
  img.to_blob
```

It gives me this really washed out orange image:

[image]

My questions is, how do I colorize this image with those rgb params in imagemagick / rmagick, to get the same vibrant color that I got in photoshop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

At the commandline, I think you want something like this:

```
convert brush.png \( +clone -fill "rgb(244,93,0)" -colorize 100% \) -compose colorize  -composite out.png
```

[image]

So, with the `+clone` I am creating another layer the same size as your image and entirely filling it 100% with your orange colour and then *composing* it over your image with the `-composite` to blend the opacity and colour.

I really don't speak Ruby, but I think it will be along these lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'RMagick'
include Magick
infile=ARGV[0]
img=Magick::Image.read(infile).first
w=img.columns
h=img.rows
ovl=Image.new(w,h){self.background_color=Magick::Pixel.new(244*256,93*256,0)}
img.composite!(ovl,0,0,Magick::ColorizeCompositeOp)
img.write('result.png')
```

Comment: Thank very much for this! ...But I'm looking to do it in rmagick, not sure how to do the convert in ruby. Also this is not quite right, see how the 'smudges' around the edge arn't white but dull and grey. The vibrant white there is super important too. I do appreciate the help.

Comment: What version on imagemagick do you have installed? That might be making the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Mark Setchell's command line works for me (Windows), with slight modifications...

```
convert greyscale.png +clone -fill "rgb(244,93,0)" -colorize 100% -compose colorize -composite colour.png
```

Found this link on recolouring with rmagick...
ftp://belagro.com/Redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.12.0/doc/colorize.rb.html

Based on the code in the above link, with the greyscale conversion removed, does the example below work (I don't have ruby)?

```
# load the greyscale image
img = Magick::Image.read('greyscale.png').first
# Colorize with a 100% blend of the orange color
colorized = img.colorize(1, 1, 1, '#A50026')
# save the colour image
colorized.write('colour.png')
```

Used a colour picker to get the hex of your orange colour - `rgb(244,93,0)` = `#A50026`